# Ban or Kick when a timer expires (Discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to code a timer set by a mod that is put into a user, when the time is out, the person automatically gets kicked or banned, or it is not able to see nothing from the server. But been really struggling.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  SO is not a code writing service, so you need to show some proof of what you've tried or what you've tried to *find* so we can help.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// make sure member = the member object
setTimeout(() => member.ban(), MILLISECONDS /* e.g 1000 for 1s */);
```